# Get date ranges from highstocks date range

Tags: highcharts

I'm using react to build some charts,  I want to update a set aggregated data based on the selected dates from the range selector on high stocks.   how would I go about doing that?

This is how I'm building my chart, examples I've found show the use of extremes but it's from  a few years ago

```
`const chartOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        events: {
            load: function () {
              var extremes = this.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
              console.log(extremes);
            },

            redraw: function () {
              var extremes = this.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
              console.log(extremes);
            }
          }
    },
```

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what do you want to achieve? As I understood you want to have a one main high stock chart and base on the range set in the `rangeSelector` of this chart show the data from this period range in the others? May I see a demo of your attempt?

Comment: Hey Sebastian, thanks, let me see if I can build one.  But for now, I'll try to provide a better explanation.   I've preloaded some data from mysql, which builds a table of data.   I pass in the start/end points of the range to filter the data down to that specific time range.


so for example my data is:
2020-05-01 | 10
2020-05-02 | 20
2020-05-03 | 30
2020-05-04 | 40
2020-05-05 | 50

total for period: 150

If I move my range selector to 2020-05-02 to 2020-05-04, I want to pass those dates so that I can filter the data and it reflects 90 for the period

Comment: Could you provide a demo with the sample data? It will be much better to understand, you can start from this template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w9hznsey/

Comment: Hey Sebastian, I actually found an old jfiddle from the forums https://jsfiddle.net/82yqp99w/. wasn't sure i could translate it over direcrtly looks like i could.. appreciate your help